# Android: Creating Events for Local Calendar Using Intents

Tags: android, calendar

I'm current working on a scheduling application which keeps track of its own events (it should not show events other than what it creates). The quickest solution was to create a new Calendar, say "MyCalendar", and just work with events inside that.

The code now creates the new local `Calendar` no problem, but to create the events themselves, it was specified that the application should just use the base Calendar application -- thus, I needed to create the events using `Intents`.

The problem is, if I use an `Intent` to create an event, I cannot set which calendar the event will be created in, as shown below:

```
/* Prepare the intent to create a new event */
Intent intent =
    new Intent(Intent.ACTION_INSERT)
        .setData(CalendarContract.Events.CONTENT_URI)
        .putExtra(
            CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME,
            startDate.getTimeInMillis())
        .putExtra(
            CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME,
            endDate.getTimeInMillis())
        /* This part doesn't work */
        .putExtra(
            CalendarContract.Events.CALENDAR_ID,
            m_datasource.getMyCalendarID());

/* ...and start the activity */
startActivityForResult(intent, Mode.Creating.getValue());
```

The resulting activity simply doesn't set the correct calendar for the new event. Is there a way around this? Any other ways of doing this?

Thanks!

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Once I create anything into that calendar, I starts working correctly.

Comment: Actually insert inter offers the last used calendar as default. Wonder if that is Calendar app issue or mine.